# Safecracker - No channel was specified

Tags: safecracker, channel

I'm trying to use Safecracker for a job application form so that all applications will be registered as entries in a channel called job_applications.

So I have this:

{exp:safecracker channel="job_applications" return="/inside_town_hall/administration/human_resources/career_opportunities"
}

[some code...]

{/exp:safecracker}

And yet when I try to view the form, I just get a "No channel was specified" error message... I double-checked (more like fifty-times-checked) the spelling of the channel and all. I even tried another of my channels as a test and none worked.
I also tried to replace the 350-or-so lines of code inside the tag pair by a basic "input name="title" type="text"" and "input type="submit" value="Submit"" and it still doesn't work.

I feel like this is probably some really stupid error but I can't think of anything. Is there some setting I have to change to make it accept my channels or something? I'm not really used to ExpressionEngine and SafeCracker so I might be forgetting something basic.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this before, and here is how I fixed it: If the user filling out the job application is not a member of the site, in Add-ons > Modules > Safecracker, you will need to "allow guests to post entries" on that channel (if you don't have a guest member account set up, you will need to create one). Then in your safecracker tag, you need to add logged_out_member_id="3" where 3 is the id of your guest member account.

Comment: Good guess, but I forgot to mention I did that already and it doesn't help :(

Comment: In the member group settings, did you allow the guest member group to post and edit entries in that channel?

Comment: yep I did... and anyway i'm trying to view the page as a logged in admin, do the problem isn't there